# KeyError "" key in dictionary not found

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to input a variable into the python file using the argparse module. The variable is a string. However, when I try to access this variable in a dictionary I get the 'KeyError' error. The call in the terminal is $python main_algo.py 'BITCOIN'. Please help. Code is below.

```
import argparse

def get_input_args():

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument('currency_pair', type = str, default = '', 
                    help = 'currency pair to trade')
    return parser.parse_args()

def calculate_balances(currency):

    my_dict = {'BITCOIN':'XXBT','XRP':'XXRP'}
    kraken = my_dict[currency]
    return kraken

def main():
    currency = get_input_args().currency_pair
    calculate_balances(currency)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I get this error:

> KeyError: "'BITCOIN'"

Comment: The call in the terminal is: `$python main_algo.py 'BITCOIN'`

Comment: What shell and operating system are you running this under?

Answer (score 2):

Look at the quotes: `"'BITCOIN'"` -- the string is including the literal single quotes.

Try `$ python main_algo.py BITCOIN`

Comment: Those quotes _should_ be interpreted by the shell before the argument is passed to the script, if this is the problem, it would be interesting to know what environment it was running in.

Comment: @SpoonMeiser agreed, though I know windows will fail to parse single quotes (which have no special meaning to the cmd shell). The use of the `$` makes me think this is a bash-alike, but that's become so standard practice anymore that it's hard to say.

Comment: @SpoonMeiser: `cmd.exe` only uses single quotes for a couple limited cases; for quoting strings in general, only double quotes are recognized/stripped (at least by the default runtime; technically, the raw string is provided, and its up to the program to parse the string, but the Windows C runtime that breaks them up into an `argv` for programs that need it uses these rules).

Comment: Thank you gentlemen for a quick response. @AdamSmith your suggestion worked. SpoonMeiser I was using the windows cmd. I should use Git. ShadowRanger I should make it my best practice to strip quotes when needed.